# wrong conversion of two bytes array to short in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to convert 2 bytes array to an unsigned short.

this is the code for the conversion :

```
short bytesToShort(char* bytesArr)
{
    short result =(short)((bytesArr[1] << 8)|bytesArr[0]);
    return result;
}
```

I have an InputFile which stores bytes, and I read its bytes via loop (2 bytes each time) and store it in char N[] arr in this manner :

```
char N[3];
N[2]='\0';

while(fread(N,1,2,inputFile)==2)
```

when the **(hex)** value of N[0]=0 the computation is correct otherwise its wrong, for example :

0x62 (N[0]=0x0,N[1]=0x62) will return 98 (in short value), **but** 0x166 in hex (N[0]=0x6,N[1]=0x16) will return 5638 (in short value).

Comment: I strongly suggest to work with unsigned types for this type of games.

Comment: the 2 things are could be biting you are endianness and sign extension that @EugeneSh. alluded to.

Comment: Please use base-specific prefixes in your question/comments. It is not clear your `66` you mention is in hex or decimal.

Comment: I would say it works correctly as for N[0]=0x06, N[1]=0x16 you get 0x1606, why would you expect it to be 0x166? 0x166 would be for N[0]=0x66, N[1]=0x01

Comment: `0x166` is `358`. But `0x1606` is `5638`. Check your math

Comment: In your question, I suggest you use 0x prefix or h suffix to indicate hex values to remove ambiguity and confusion.  And do not use quotation mark-up if you are not quoting something.

Comment: Quote: "62 in hex (N[0]=0,N[1]=62) will return 98 ..." really? I that case my system is very broken... how about 25088 instead. I think you have misunderstod how data is stored in your file. Maybe you need to swap the index so that it is index 0 that is shifted

Comment: 0x1606 == 5638 decimal is easily explained (because it is correct) - what is incorrect is your error in missing the place value.  However, the real mystery is how you got 98dec from 0x6200 ?!  It is  25088 decimal.  It seems to me you have not really tested this code, or even actually executed it.

Comment: @4386427 a simple endianness error is not the issue here - the two examples quoted have _different_ endianness.  More likely he made the first example up without using real test results and got it wrong.

Comment: @Clifford We can't know what is wrong as long as we haven't got an example of the input file and know the values it's supposed to represent. However, it's obvious 1) that OP haven't tested the posted code as the posted result for the said input is just wrong 2) that OP don't really understand how a hex number maps into the char array and 3) that OP haven't posted a complete code example as the function is never called. In short - we can't help OP as the question is incomplete.

Comment: @4386427 : I am not saying we know what is wrong, simply that the suggestion "_Maybe you need to swap the index_" is not a solution to the second example - they are inconsistent, so in that sense we are in _violent agreement_ - the question is flawed in several ways.

Comment: @Clifford I didn't say that either... but the first example suggest that. Anyway - as long we don't get the information from OP this Q should just be closed.

Answer (score 3):

In the first place, it's generally best to use type `unsigned char` for the bytes of raw binary data, because that correctly expresses the semantics of what you're working with.  Type `char`, although it can be, and too frequently is, used as a synonym for "byte", is better reserved for data that are actually character in nature.

In the event that you are furthermore performing arithmetic on byte values, you almost surely want `unsigned char` instead of `char`, because the signedness of `char` is implementation-defined.  It does vary among implementations, and on many common implementations `char` is *signed*.

With that said, your main problem appears simple.  You said

> 166 in hex (N[0]=6,N[1]=16) will return 5638 (in short value).

but 0x166 packed into a two-byte little-endian array would be (N[0]=0x66,N[1]=0x1).  What you wrote would correspond to 0x1606, which indeed is the same as decimal 5638.

Answer (score 1):

<s>The problem is sign extension due to using `char`.</s> You should use `unsigned char` instead:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

short bytesToShort(unsigned char* bytesArr)
{
    short result = (short)((bytesArr[1] << 8) | bytesArr[0]);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%04x\n", bytesToShort("\x00\x11")); // expect 0x1100
    printf("%04x\n", bytesToShort("\x55\x11")); // expect 0x1155
    printf("%04x\n", bytesToShort("\xcc\xdd")); // expect 0xddcc

    return 0;
}
```

**Note**: the problem in the code is not the one presented by the OP. The problem is returning the wrong result upon the input `"\xcc\xdd"`. It will produce `0xffcc` where it should be `0xddcc`

Comment: Although the OP's code *is* susceptible to issues arising from sign extension (on implementations where `char` is signed), that's not the reason for the specific failure they described in their question.

Comment: Yes, but the signed char version produced the wrong result in the case `\xcc\xdd`. I checked :)

Comment: That's as I already stipulated, albeit only for implementations on which `char` is signed.  Those are common, so it's not surprising that yours is one.

Comment: That may be the case but it is not the reason for the OPs results which are one of erroneous expectation rather than erroneous code (even if the code is also erroneous).  You clearly state "_The problem is sign extension..._", but that is a different problem.